# UnitTesting. Reach the classes from other project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have two projects in my solution. One of of them is a unitTest-project. And I want to reach my model-classes from the other project in the solution, but I can't find out how to do it! I've tried to set dependencies.. what to do? please help

Comment: Are your classes public or internal?

Comment: then just add a reference in the unit test project to the other project and include the namespace(s) where the classes are located